# unit testing removeAt function on AbstractControl and FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I have a function that takes in an AbstractControl FormArray and an index and removes an entry from the FormArray, however I cannot seem to test the function correctly?

**This is the function that currently works when using my app**

```
remove(data: AbstractControl, index: number) {
   data['controls'].myArray.removeAt(index);
}
```

**Here is my test**

```
it('Should delete item from array', () => {
    const fb = new FormBuilder();
    const something= fb.group(exampleData);

    component.remove(something, 0);
 expect(component.myFormGroup.controls['myArray'].value.myArray.size).toEqual(0);
  });
```

I am getting an error message of:

> 'removeAt' is not a function associated with AbstractControl type...

Comment: Firstly, that test case doesn't seem to invoke `remove`. Secondly, that's a test of *implementation*, rather than *behaviour*; I'd advise thinking about it more in terms of what you expect the visible result to be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Whoops, I accidentally didn't include it in my test example XD

Comment: @jonrsharpe - With regards to your comment... I would expect to see `myArray` to have decreased in size by 1 after `remove(...)` had been run. That is the purpose of the function. I believe my test outlines this (assuming that I have 1 element in my array to begin with)?